# How to initialize cookie in WebClient

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551345/accept-cookies-in-webclient) question's most voted answer there is this line :

```
cookieJar.Add(new Cookie("my_cookie", "cookie_value", "/", "mysite"));
```

In this line, there are "my_cookie", cookie_value and "mysite" fields. I don't know how to fill these lines. Can you tell me how to fill those with an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oo? You'll pass the variable values into it.

Comment: `my_cookie` is the name of the cookie

Comment: `cookie_value` is the value that will be stored in the client

Comment: if you're using .net4.5 I'd recommend to use `HttpClient` instead

Comment: Just read what is cookie anywhere, even wikipedia will do.

Comment: Most of the times, you don't have to set cookies yourself, you just send back the cookies the server sent you. Otherwise, well, you're supposed to know what you must sent back, the server developer should basically tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpCookie _cookie = new HttpCookie("Department"); // Create and give name
_cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);       // expries in one month
_cookie.Value = "Dep1";                          // set value
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(_cookie);      // add cookie to the context
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this Helps

```
CookieContainer gaCookies = new CookieContainer();
Uri target = new Uri("http://www.google.com/");    
gaCookies.Add(new Cookie("__utmc", "#########") { Domain = target.Host });
```

or head [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckch3yd2(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information