# WebClient to download file not working on production server

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm currently using WebClient to download files from passing specific urls,
though the downloading is working perfectly on localhost but once it's published on the production server it always gives "404".

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
    var data = client.DownloadData(filePath);
    var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
    var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
    return File(content, contentType, file);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the problem with cookies. read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551345/accept-cookies-in-webclient/14551410#14551410

Comment: @PritomSarkar I think it's not relevant

Comment: @MomenMewali post your code.

Comment: @Momen Use a ```try``` ```catch``` WebException in your code.

Comment: 404 means the file is not found,is `filePath` correct on the production server?

Comment: @YiyiYou It exists and it works well on localhost